# Is defined conditional passing, yet causes a "do not have a method or closure named" error

Tags: templating, conditional, plugin-supertable, defined

Why is it that in the below, referencing stRow.caption causes an error despite being wrapped in an "if defined" check?

The error is:

> Craft\SuperTable_BlockModel and its behaviors do not have a method or
>   closure named "caption".

I have to be doing something so catastrophically dumb that it's not sticking out yeah?

---

```
{% if stRow.caption is defined %}
    {% set caption = stRow.caption %} <<- This line causes the error
{% endif %}
```

Same with using a null coelescing operator or a ternary operand.

```
{{ stRow.caption ?? "" }} <<- This causes the error
-- or --
{{ stRow.caption is defined ? stRow.caption : "" }}  <<- This causes the error too!
```

All three of those should work.

Supertable: 1.0.4
Craft CMS: 2.6.2997

Comment: Did you try `| length` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a weird twig behavior. You have to do `if   stRow['caption'] is defined` to make it work because of the object syntax of twig.

Sometimes the if defined statement becomes true when you don't use the array syntax

Comment: Huh... weird. That totally fixed it. Thanks Robin! That's a fairly specific little piece of knowledge that should probably be really up front in the docs. Thanks for your help.